# The screen is black using latest VNCview 6.21.118 X64(Jan 14 2021) to connect build server Ubuntu

Tags: display, screen, macbook, trash, document

The screen is black with only "trash" and "documents" using latest VNCview 6.21.118 X64(Jan 14 2021) to connect build server Ubuntu 16 Dev Server on MacBook Pro.
I used the line below to start vncserver with diff geometry:

```
vncserver -auth ~/.Xauthority -pn -geometry 1280x1024 :88 &
```

I am blocked here and appreciate your any help.

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu 16?  So this is a *snap* only system like Ubuntu Core 16.  All desktop, server and *deb* based systems use the *yy.mm* format for releases, there is no Ubuntu 16, but your format implies is one of the specialist *snap* only based releases like Ubuntu Core - is that correct?

Comment: uname -a
Linux curium 4.4.0-193-generic #224-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 6 17:15:28 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[Ubuntu 16 Dev Server]

Comment: `uname` provides details of the linux kernel, which doesn't provide much useful information at all; as that kernel is used by many systems (not all of which are on-topic on this site).